# table layout full width and width with first tr only 40px in height and rest filling page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want whole page in table layout
1: 1st tr will have height 40px
2: 2nd tr will cover rest space

like **case a**: device height:1000px

first tr will be 40px and and rest will be of 960px

like **case a**: device height:800px

first tr will be 40px and and rest will be of 860px

like wise same in all case as window resizes fro device of height H px

first tr of height:40px and rest (H-40)px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this gets you close. It uses CSS table styles on div tags. The top row is 40px and the rest will expand or shrink to fit the browser window. As quoted from your question the "1st tr will have height 40px 2: 2nd tr will cover rest space."

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/9jvmyy1p/)

The trick is setting the html, body and wrapper to height 100%.

```
html{
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
}

body { 
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;  
}

.wrapper {
height:100%;
width:100%;
display:table;
border-style:none;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

The cell in the top row has a height of 40px.

```
.cell-top {
display:table-cell;
height:40px;
}
```

I think you'll be happier with the CSS tables because they are a modern solution and are more versatile, versus an HTML table.

---

### Update

Here is an updated JSFiddle using an HTML Table. Because you are nesting the table within an existing table, you will not need the html or body CSS (used for the JSFiddle display). But you will need to set the following css to make the nested table fill the space.

[HTML Table JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/43343h93/)

```
.nested-table {
height:100%;
width:100%;
border-style:none;
border-collapse:collapse;
}

.cell-top {
height:40px;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="nested-table">
<tr>
<td class="cell-top">Top 40px</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cell-bottom">Bottom</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Resize the browser window in the JSFiddle to see the table adjust to the different sizes, and you can experiment with the code.

Comment: basically i want table inside table in more deep so i will prefer using table, i do not have deep knlowdge of css

Comment: An html table example was added to the answer, along with a JSFiddle example. You can nest this inside another table.

Comment: what do u think about http://liveweave.com/Ghyihe
using height="calc(100% - 40px)"

Comment: Calc is good too, but browser support may be an issue for your users? Click the "Show All" button to see the calc browser support http://caniuse.com/#search=calc. In the 2nd JSFiddle example above browser support is very good. Instead of "calc(100% - 40px)", it says make the table 100% high, set the 1st row at 40px and let the 2nd row automatically fill the remaining space.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to achieve the behavior you are describing. Let me outline a few:

Also, you shouldn't be using full tables to stylize pages. Things should be done in pure CSS, but I digress.

**CSS: Responsive Design**

You could use the `CSS` `media` selector to determine the size of the screen and adjust the pixel width of the table accordingly.

```
@media all and (max-width: 100px) and (min-width: 800px), (min-width: 1151px) {

    tr:nth-of-type(1) {
        width: 40px;
    }
    tr:nth-of-type(2) {
        width: 760px;
    }
}
```

Then you would keep writing values for other screen sizes. This would produce a 'stepped' effect; it's probably not as accurate as what you are going for.

**SASS: CSS Preprocessor**

You could also use some sort of CSS preprocessor that treats other elements like variables so you can do basic math operations and calculate the width that way.

**Javascript**

I would recommend using Javascript to solve this problem, although it is of note that this solution has some drawbacks (what if the user doesn't support Javascript - it's rare, but can happen). Have a fallback.

The code for this should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var width = $(document).width(); // the width of the screen

    document.getElementById("tr1").style.width = "40px";
    document.getElementById("tr2").style.width = (width - 40) + "px";
});
```

You can also include this logic in a resize function:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    var width = $(document).width(); // the width of the screen

    document.getElementById("tr1").style.width = "40px";
    document.getElementById("tr2").style.width = (width - 40) + "px";
};
```

Comment: Okay, I updated the question to discuss the methods for achieving this. Let me know if you want me to go more specifically into any one methodology I mentioned.

Comment: SASS: CSS Preprocessor ??